# Can one of my Angular models watch another?

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of companies that have revenue and cost data. In my app, either revenue or cost can be displayed, and the list can be filtered down by a query.

In my controller I have the following **two watches**:

```
$scope.$watch('query', function(q) {
  $scope.filteredCompanies = $scope.companies
    .filter(function(c) { return q ? c.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) > -1 : true; });

  $scope.chartData = {
    name: 'companies',
    children: $scope.filteredCompanies.map(function(c) { 
      return {name: c.name, size: c[$scope.selectedItem]};
    })
  };
});

$scope.$watch('selectedItem', function(i) {
  $scope.chartData = {
    name: 'companies',
    children: $scope.filteredCompanies.map(function(c) { 
      return {name: c.name, size: c[i]};
    })
  };
});
```

My question is, can I tell `chartData` to watch `selectedItem` and `filteredCompanies`, instead of `query`? I tried the following:

```
$scope.$watch('[filteredCompanies, selectedItem]', function(arr) {
  $scope.chartData = {
    name: 'companies',
    children: arr[0].map(function(c) { 
      return {name: c.name, size: c[arr[1]]};
    })
  };
});
```

but got the `10 digests iterations reached` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what version of angular you are using.. but the 1.2 version of that is..

```
$scope.$watchCollection('[filteredCompanies, selectedItem]', 
    function(newValues, oldValues){
    $scope.chartData = {
      name: 'companies',
      children: arr[0].map(function(c) { 
         return {name: c.name, size: c[arr[1]]};
      })
    };
});
```

I also think a third parameter of true will work:

```
$scope.$watch('[filteredCompanies, selectedItem]', 
    function () {
    }, 
    true
 );
```

Setting up a fiddle now.

Comment: While I have you - is there a more declarative way to say that `chartData` depends on `filteredCompanies` and `selectedItem`, or is this pretty much the way I'm supposed to do this sort of thing?

Comment: Its really hard to infer what you want to do...  I think I would need to know what selectedIndex is, and how you use chartData.children....